# Creating a dynamic 2D array to store class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So I have a class called Cell, and I need to create a new Cell and put it into a 2d array. I believe the problem is how I created the 2D array. I have looked up how dynamic arrays work but I still can't find the problem. Below is some of my code and the first few errors I get

```
    Cell * board = new Cell[h]; //create new board
        for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){
            board[i] = new Cell[w];
            }
        for (int row = 0; row < h; row ++){     //initialize board
            for (int col = 0; col < w; col++){
                board[row][col] = new Cell; 
                board[row][col]->status = '#';
                board[row][col]->isCovered = true;
            }
        }
```

ERRORS:

```
minesweeper.h: In constructor ‘GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int, int)’:
minesweeper.h:29:17: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are 
‘Cell’ and ‘Cell*’)
    board[i] = new Cell[w];
             ^
minesweeper.h:29:17: note: candidate is:
minesweeper.h:4:8: note: Cell& Cell::operator=(const Cell&)
 struct Cell
    ^
minesweeper.h:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Cell*’ 
to ‘const Cell&’
minesweeper.h:33:16: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are 
‘Cell’ and ‘int’)
      board[row][col] = new Cell; 
            ^
minesweeper.h:34:16: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are 
‘Cell’ and ‘int’)
      board[row][col]->status = '#';
                ^
```

Comment: You initialized the array for 1D instead 2D.

Comment: Before you attempt a 2D array of a custom class, try a 2D array of `int`. That way you can iron these problems out before you introduce a lot of new unknowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
Cell* board = new Cell[h]
```

to

```
Cell** board = new Cell*[h]
```

Basically you want to create a 2d array, so you need to create and array of `Cell` pointers (`new Cell*[h]`). Then for each of those Cell pointers you want to allocate memory for each individual Cell. This is done in the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h; i++){
    board[i] = new Cell[w];
}
```

Comment: this gives me the error:                                                                            
`In file included from minesweeper.cpp:2:0:
minesweeper.h: In constructor ‘GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int, int)’:
minesweeper.h:27:30: error: cannot convert ‘Cell*’ to ‘Cell**’ in initialization
    Cell ** board = new Cell[h]; //create new board`

Comment: That's because you didn't make the change properly. Read the post again.

Comment: Sorry about that! (running on very little sleep) New Error: 'minesweeper.h: In constructor ‘GameBoard::GameBoard(int, int, int)’:
minesweeper.h:33:22: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Cell’ and ‘Cell*’)
      board[row][col] = new Cell; 
                      ^
'

Comment: You don't need that line. You've already created the Cell at that row and col in the loop above.